# Ambiguous use of infinitive after "It's needed"

Tags: prepositions, ambiguity, infinitives, dummy-it

After writing this sentence, I found myself thinking that its meaning may be a little confusing to other people:

> It’s needed to make clear some issues regarding absences.

I used the phrase *to make clear &c* to indicate **what** is needed. But every time I read this sentence, it seems like the phrase is being used to indicate purpose: the reason **why** it's needed.

Is it easy for native speakers of English to understand this sentence?

Additionally, how can one write sentences in a way that avoids kind of situation?

Comment: The only thing I would change is to put *clear* after *issues*.

Comment: Or use 'clarify' instead.

Comment: Luke, don't you mean before issues ?

Comment: If you make one of the suggested changes, the sentence is grammatical. And the meaning would be "This is needed to...". But, I wonder if you meant to say: "What is needed is to clarify certain issues regarding absences".

Comment: Neil, that's exactly what I want to say.

Comment: Certain issues regarding absences need to be [made clear/clarified].

Comment: @NeilCofey: Very clever. My respect for figuring this one out. You could post it as an answer?

Comment: Also, someone please point out already that *to* is not a preposition there, much less a proposition. Thanks!

Comment: @egDwight: Why not?

Comment: Better would be to lead with the subject: "Certain issues regarding absences must be addressed."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Neil and you have shown in the comments, you're not using the right construction here. You are trying to use *it* as a dummy subject, to be picked up by *to make clear*. But that is only possible in English with words that cannot take an infinitive themselves:

> It's better to make these issues clear.

Here, the dummy subject *it* is picked up by the subject complement, which is the infinitive plus dependencies: *to make these issues clear*. It is possible because *better* doesn't take an infinitive itself, so that there is no cause for ambiguity. It means "making these issues clear is better".

> It's needed to make these issues clear.

Because *needed* can take the infinitive, the same construction is not possible here. Readers will take *needed* as governing *to make...*, as you said. The sentence then means "this is needed in order to make these issues clear". That is why you need to cut *needed* loose from the infinitive to get the desired reading while keeping the infinitive, as Neil suggested above:

> What is needed is to make these issues clear.

This means "making these issues clear is needed".

Comment: Cerberus, but I'm using 'needed' as an adjective here, so it can't an infinite.

Comment: @utxeee: Can you clarify this comment?

Comment: In my quoted sentence I was using the word 'needed' as a adjective, so, it could not take an infinitive because it was not even acting as verb.

Comment: Not so. Many adjectives, including participial adjectives, take a to-infinitive: We will be delighted to attend. He was happy to see his sister. He is keen to come. ( http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/infinitive3c.html )

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is with the word *needed*. Why not try

> It is *necessary* to make some issues regarding absences clear.

or

> It is *necessary* to make some issues clear regarding absences.

Comment: Yes. It is needful... also works and is obviously closer to the original, but It is necessary... is the preferred construction.

Answer (score 1):

I'd reword the sentence and use the verb *clarify* (or rather its noun, *clarification*), eg.:

> Some issues regarding absences need clarification.

This is easier to understand and avoids the need for the dummy pronoun *it*.